# error installing android studio in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

[image]

I'm getting this error while installing Android Studio on my PC. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install from official site [android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the [ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio](https://launchpad.net/~paolorotolo/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio) to your system? As described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html), this PPA is just for installing Android Studio and *not for updating* it, because Android Studio has its own update "manager".

> 'To update Android Studio to the latest version, simply click "Check
>   for updates now" in the welcome screen, then click "Update and
>   Restart"'